# Ways of setting/getting a textNode's value

Tags: javascript, dom, textnode

There are many ways to retrieve/change the value of a text node:

- It's *not* [`textnode.value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Attribute/textnode.value), a [XUL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL)-only thing
- [`textContent`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Node3-textContent)<sup>[[mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.textContent)]</sup> is not supported until IE9
- [`data`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-72AB8359), inherited by `Text` from the `CharacterData` interface
- [`nodeValue`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-F68D080)<sup>[[mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.nodeValue)]</sup> from the `Node` interface

I tend to use `.data`. Which of them is recommended - they all return the same?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a TEXT_NODE [type 3] textContent will return the nodeValue ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.textContent#Description)):

> If the node is a CDATA section, a comment, a processing instruction,
>   or a text node, textContent returns the text inside this node (the
>   nodeValue).

CharacterData is the same as nodeValue for text nodes ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/CharacterData)).

> Text, Comment, and CDATASection all implement CharacterData, which in
>   turn also implements Node.

For text nodes they are the same.

jQuery (Sizzle) uses nodeValue:

```
/**
 * Utility function for retreiving the text value of an array of DOM nodes
 * @param {Array|Element} elem
 */
var getText = Sizzle.getText = function( elem ) {
    ...
    if ( nodeType === 1 || nodeType === 9 || nodeType === 11 ) {
        // Use textContent || innerText for elements
        if ( typeof elem.textContent === 'string' ) {
            return elem.textContent;
        } else if ( typeof elem.innerText === 'string' ) {
            // Replace IE's carriage returns
            return elem.innerText.replace( rReturn, '' );
        }
        ...
    // TEXT_NODE
    } else if ( nodeType === 3 || nodeType === 4 ) {
        return elem.nodeValue;
    }
    return ret;
};
```

So using data is fine, but textContent is IE9+ only and a bit slower.